# How to clear 307 internal redirect (from disk cache) on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cache

I'm facing a really strange issue. The issue is when I type the URL microsoft.com in my chrome it redirects me to google.com.

I have tried to clear browser cache, clear everything, uninstall/re-install Chrome, clear User_Data folder but nothing helps.

It's redirecting even I after I've set network to offline via inspector window.

When I see the network traffic for microsoft.com, for the Request URL (GET) is getting Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect (from disk cache).

Note: It works fine in Incognito mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works fine in Incognito mode, this means that the problem
is caused by an extension.

To find the extension, enter the following URL : `chrome://extensions/`,
disable some extensions and restart Chrome and check.
Continue until you find the extension that is responsible.

Note very well the source of the extension - if it is part of
some installed product, that product should probably be uninstalled.

I also suggest to do deep antivirus scans with your antivirus and
also with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Comment: I tried to disable all extensions, but the issue is still there

Comment: Does it work in another browser (Firefox, Edge) ?

Comment: yes,it works in firefox, edge, chrome incognito. It redirects to google.com even if the internet is off

Comment: Seems like an extension that is hidden from the extensions list, or something that is outside of Chrome. Does it happen when booting in Safe Mode with Network?

Comment: yeah it was an extension which I could not uninstall

Comment: I had the same issue with other domains. In my case, although it worked in incognito mode, it wasn't any extension. Clearing cache fixed it.